# Is there a way to get youtube videos in users subscription list which are older than 1 week

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I want to get videos from users subscription list which are older than one week,

As specified on google developers site

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_subscriptions#Retrieving_new_subscription_videos

to get subscription videos we need to use following GDATA request,

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/*userid*/newsubscriptionvideos

But it only returns list of videos which are less than one week old.

So is there any way we can get fixed number of videos from subscription list independent of time.

Any help Really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) and use [subscriptions->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) method for that.

If you specify the user's channel id, you will get all of his channel's subscriptions.

Request will be:

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&id={USERS_CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: i got total count of subscription but i want retrieve name (who subscription the channel)  please help